# SQL value contains a line feed?

Tags: .net, sql

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE SQLTestTable (sqltest VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO SQLTestTable (sqltest) values ('INSERT INTO Person VALUES (''SELECT * FROM PERSON --THIS IS A TEST WHERE ID=1'')')

INSERT INTO SQLTestTable (sqltest) values ('INSERT INTO Person VALUES (
''SELECT * FROM --THIS IS A TEST 
PERSON WHERE ID=1'')')
```

Notice that in the first INSERT statement it is all on one line, whereas in INSERT statement two it is not.  If I extract the sqltest value into SQLCommand.CommandText and execute the SQLCommand, then it works for the second insert but not the first i.e. it does not work for the first because the comment causes a syntax error.  Is a line feed stored in the database somehow for the second insert?

Comment: You know you can use `/* comment */` without the need of a line feed?

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: @DanBracuk The syntax error occurs when he tries to execute  `INSERT INTO Person VALUES (''SELECT * FROM PERSON --...`.  OP is not asking why this occurs, but rather how the second value gets stored since it includes the linebreaks to form valid SQL.

Comment: @Taemyr, thanks.  You have correctly understood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line feeds gets stored in the database.  Probably as carriage return followed by line feed.  (ASCII symbol 10 and 13).

Comment: Thanks. That is what I thought. Is there any documentation to support this?

Comment: It's general behavior for strings.

Comment: @w0051977 A string contains the characters between the opening `'` and the closing `'`. You have CR and LF characters between the opening `'` and the closing `'`. That means the string contains those characters. There isn't documentation that those characters have a special meaning, just like there isn't documentation that, for example, `+` has no special meaning in `'+'`. It's that lack of documentation of an exception that supports this. :)

Answer (score 0):

If u want to remove New line character and tab character, then use the below Query:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column_name, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

Comment: Why three replaces?  Ie. why do you first remove lfcr, then cr, then lf.  Am I wrong to think that removing cr, then lf would also remove lfcr?